# conditional either or validation in asp.net mvc2

Tags: asp.net-mvc-2, validation

In my registration page I have land line phone number and mobile number fields.

I need to ensure that the user needs to add at least one phone number either the land line or mobile.

How do I do this?

Thanks
Arnab

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You could write a custom validation attribute and decorate your model with it:

```
[AttributeUsage(AttributeTargets.Class)]
public class AtLeastOnePhoneAttribute: ValidationAttribute
{
    public override bool IsValid(object value)
    {
        var model = value as SomeViewModel;
        if (model != null)
        {
            return !string.IsNullOrEmpty(model.Phone1) ||
                   !string.IsNullOrEmpty(model.Phone2);
        }
        return false;
    }
}
```

and then:

```
[AtLeastOnePhone(ErrorMessage = "Please enter at least one of the two phones")]
public class SomeViewModel
{
    public string Phone1 { get; set; }
    public string Phone2 { get; set; }
}
```

For more advanced validation scenarios you may take a look at [FluentValidation.NET](http://fluentvalidation.codeplex.com/) or [Foolproof](http://foolproof.codeplex.com/).

Comment: The validation is working but error message is not showing, the required validations added against individual fields are showing, As in this case I'm adding the validation annotation to the class do I need to do something extra

Comment: @Arnab, validation message will show with the `ValidationSummary` helper. Because this is a class level validator it is not associated to any property so the key added to model state is empty. If you want to associate it to some of the fields you will need to use other frameworks such as the ones I've linked to in my answer because this is not supported by Data Annotations.

Comment: Validation Summary is there but it does not show. Could it be because I am using the annotation in models and model is inside viewmodel which is being called in views.

Comment: @Arnab, are you using it like this: `<%= Html.ValidationSummary(true) %>`?

Comment: +1 for pointing me to Foolproof. I had the either-or problem, and Foolproof solved it with the "[RequiredIfEmpty]" attribute.

Answer (score 1):

Adding a solution that can be applied to individual properties, rather than overriding the validation method at the class level...

Create the following custom attribute. Note the "otherPropertyName" parameter in the constructor. This will allow you to pass in the other property to use in validation.

```
public class OneOrOtherRequiredAttribute: ValidationAttribute
{
    public string OtherPropertyName { get; set; }
    public OneOrOtherRequiredAttribute(string otherPropertyName)
    {
        OtherPropertyName = otherPropertyName;
    }

    protected override ValidationResult IsValid(object value, ValidationContext validationContext)
    {
        var otherPropertyInfo = validationContext.ObjectType.GetProperty(OtherPropertyName);
        var otherValue = (string)otherPropertyInfo.GetValue(validationContext.ObjectInstance, null);
        if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(otherValue) && string.IsNullOrEmpty((string)value))
        {
            return new ValidationResult(this.ErrorMessage); //The error message passed into the Attribute's constructor
        }
        return null;
    }
}
```

You can then decorate your properties like so: (be sure to pass in the name of the other property to compare with)

```
[OneOrOtherRequired("GroupNumber", ErrorMessage = "Either Group Number or Customer Number is required")]
public string CustomerNumber { get; set; }

[OneOrOtherRequired("CustomerNumber", ErrorMessage="Either Group Number or Customer Number is required")]
public string GroupNumber { get; set; }
```