# How to handle validation  when only one of two fields is required

Tags: .net, asp.net-mvc, validation

In my application a forms needs to be completed by inserting a phonenumber **or** cellphonenumber. how do you make this possible in ASP MVC ?

```
   <MetadataType(GetType(Persoon_Metadata))> _
Partial Public Class Persoon

End Class


Partial Public Class Persoon_Metadata

    <DisplayName("Voornaam:")> _
    <Required(ErrorMessage:="Gelieve een voornaam op te geven.")> _
    <DisplayFormat(ConvertEmptyStringToNull:=False)>
    Property Voornaam As Object

    <DisplayName("Familienaam:")> _
    <Required(ErrorMessage:="Gelieve een familienaam op te geven.")> _
    <DisplayFormat(ConvertEmptyStringToNull:=False)>
    Property Familienaam As Object

    '<RegularExpression("[0-9]", ErrorMessage:="Het opgegeven telefoonnumer voldoet niet aan het gewenste formaat. (bv 050123456)")> _
    <DisplayName("Telefoonnummer:")> _
    <Required(ErrorMessage:="Gelieve een telefoonnummer op te geven aub")> _
    <StringLength(15, ErrorMessage:="Het opgegeven telefoonnummer voldoet niet aan het gewenste formaat. (bv 050123456)", MinimumLength:=9)> _
    <DisplayFormat(ConvertEmptyStringToNull:=False)>
    Property Telefoonnummer As Object

    '<Required(ErrorMessage:="Gelieve een gsmnummer op te geven aub")> _
    <DisplayName("GSM - nummer:"), DisplayFormat(ConvertEmptyStringToNull:=False)>
    <StringLength(15, ErrorMessage:="Het opgegeven gsmnummer voldoet niet aan het gewenste formaat. (bv 050123456)", MinimumLength:=9)> _
    Property Gsmnummer As Object

    <Required(ErrorMessage:="Gelieve een functie op te geven bv. directeur , technisch assistent ...")> _
    <DisplayFormat(ConvertEmptyStringToNull:=False)> _
    <DisplayName("Functie:")> _
    Property Functie As Object


End Class
```

Comment: See if this post helps http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5543012/conditional-either-or-validation-in-asp-net-mvc2

Comment: @Bala This did the trick , i wrote my own version based on Darins answer

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Seems you've hit on a case where attribute-based validation falls on its face. May I suggest that you check out [Fluent Validation](http://fluentvalidation.codeplex.com/)?

Comment: can you combine fluent validation with data-annotaions?